# mysql typo error

Tags: mysql, xampp

i have installed xampp on my linux (suse) pc. and started lampp with command

> /opt/lampp/lampp start

it says:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.4...
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)...
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

but when i try to connect to database using

> mysql -u root -p

it gives me following error:

```
If 'mysql' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf mysql
```

can some one tell me how to fix this error. please

Comment: Is the MySQL commandline client installed? What does `whereis mysql` give?

Answer (score 0):

Actually , when u install there is by default password is set for mysql user `root`, so u have to change the password or use that password to connect your mysql

Reference

[Linux with mysql](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMySQL.html)